# How to set payment amount to be passed in msg.value

Tags: solidity, truffle, error, transfer, bignumber

I am working on truffle (solc 0.5) and trying to fetch amount in wei from user and send it to another account. Following is my code:

```
contract pay {

  uint amount;
  function payment(uint _amount, address payable _ID) external payable {
        
        amount = _amount;
        _ID.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

I typed in the following command in truffle console:

> var contract = await name.deployed()
> then
> await contract.pay(10000000000000000, accounts[1], {value: amount})

I received an error after executing `payment` function as:

> reason: 'overflow',
> code: 'NUMERIC_FAULT',
> fault: 'overflow',
> operation: 'BigNumber.from',
> value: 10000000000000000,

What should I do in order to send fetched amount from the account calling the function to another account? What should I change in order for it to work properly? A code for reference would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the value as a string, example - `"10000000000000000"`. Or if it's dynamic value you could use `.toString()` method.